# Google Login Audit Increased lag time

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to get login events for domain users of a customer.

Following is the api , i am using --

GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/login?startTime={startTime}&maxResults=1000

I am not getting any login event after 2018-02-01T17:38:13.000Z, These seems to be a bug.

I have tried the above for multiple customers, all having the same issue. Non of them have the latest data. (I know of the lag time in login events but it is more than 24hrs since the last login event)

PS. we have been using the same api for a long time now,  This is the first time we are seeing this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What used to work? And what did you change that caused your program to not act as expected?

Comment: The google login audit api use to work as expected, but now the response gives old logins data with almost 24 hrs lag. There has been no change in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have acknowledged this bug.

They have fixed it from their side. Everything is working fine as expected.